# How to delete strings after certain character in multiple files using batch?

Tags: batch-file, scripting

I have been trying to delete some characters after _1 and rename the file but got stuck. let me put in sample file names to make it clear.

```
aero_name_1_3_7.png
glik_trol_1_5_2_9_5.png
this_that_1_3_1_9.png
....... and so on.
```

So my filenames contain exact format but different names and hence I thought to use tokens and delims. After renaming my files should look aero_name_1.png, glik_trol_1.png, this_that_1.png
 Here is the piece of bat that I wrote but this does not work. If someone could suggest, that would be great.

```
for /F "tokens=1-4,* delims=_" %%a in ('dir /A-D /B "*.png"') do (
  move "%%a_%%b" "%%a%%~xb"
)
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking at your 2nd file name, this is what the FOR /F loop has:

```
%%a=glik
%%b=trol
%%c=1
%%d=5
%%e=2_9_5.png
```

So your MOVE command becomes:

```
move "glik_trol" "glik"
```

Note that `%%b` has no extension

You could use

```
for /f "tokens=1-3* delims=_" %%a in ('dir /a-d /b *.png') do (
  move "%%a_%%b_%%c_%%d" "%%a_%%b_%%c%%~xd"
)
```

If you are comfortable with regular expressions, then you could use my handy [JREN.BAT utility](http://www.dostips.com/forum/viewtopic.php?f=3&t=6081) - a hybrid JScript/batch script that renames files by performing a regular expression find and replace on the name. [JREN.BAT](http://www.dostips.com/forum/viewtopic.php?f=3&t=6081) is pure script that runs natively on any Windows machine from XP onward. It is a very convenient method to perform very precise rename operations.

Assuming you have [JREN.BAT](http://www.dostips.com/forum/viewtopic.php?f=3&t=6081) in your current directory, or better yet, somewhere within your PATH:

```
jren "^([^_]+_[^_]+_[^_]+)_.*(\.png)$" "$1$2" /i
```

No batch is needed. If you do use the command in a batch script, then you should prefix the command with `CALL` because JREN is also a batch script.

Comment: Thank you for your prompt reply. I ended up correcting mine with your suggestion. This is what I used:                                                            for /f "tokens=1-4* delims=_" %%a in ('dir /a-d /b *.png') do (
  move "%%a_%%b_%%c_%%d_%%e" "%%a_%%b_%%c%%_%%d%%~xe")               I used it to change files that looks like this: glik_trol_this_1_2_9_5.png and it removed s from this and inserted a % sign. Dont have any idea how that happened. Thanks

Comment: I ended up using his correction. But thank you both for your input. Did help a lot!!!!

Answer (score 1):

From your requirements, "delete some characters after _1", it appears that the best solution would be to use [substring substitution](http://www.dostips.com/DtTipsStringManipulation.php).  Not sure whether you will benefit from this, but this solution will allow for a variable number of underscores before the `_1` as well -- unlike the more static use of `"delims=_"` you're using now.

Substring substitution is great for stripping parts off the beginning (`set "var=%var:*_1=%"` for example), but stripping off the end is a little trickier.  One way to do this is to shove a `rem` into the replacement.

Try this:

```
@echo off
setlocal

for %%I in (*.png) do call :ren "%%~I"

goto :EOF

:ren <filename>
set "pngfile=%~1"
echo "%pngfile%" | find "_1" >NUL || goto :EOF
set pngfile=%pngfile:_1=&rem.%
echo ren "%~1" "%pngfile%_1.png"
```

Comment: @user2516780 See edit.  I added a line to skip renaming of png files that don't contain `_1`.  If you're saying you need your files to end up in the format of `basename1.png` then remove the underscore from the last line.

Comment: Thank you! this works... I did correct another one as well. Thanks a lot